# ORA-01841: need to compare a converted string to sysdate

Tags: oracle10g

here is the query I'm using

```
select * from (
select table_name, to_number(to_char(trunc(to_date(substr(table_name,instr(table_name,'_',-1,2)+1,8),'yyyymmdd')),'J')) as t_date, to_number(to_char(trunc(sysdate),'J')) as s_date
  from user_tables
 where table_name like 'WORLD_RI%' and table_name not like 'WORLD_RI_ERROR%' )
where t_date < s_date;
```

I get

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

error with inclusion of the last where clause (`where t_date < s_date`). Also FYI, the table_name is typically like `WORLD_RI_1234_20120301_1`.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running just this part

```
select table_name
, substr(table_name,instr(table_name,'_',-1,2)+1,8) as t_date
from user_tables
where table_name like 'WORLD_RI%' 
and table_name not like 'WORLD_RI_ERROR%'
```

then manually check for odd looking values in your data

edit:

if that part works - then try this part

```
select table_name
, to_date(substr(table_name,instr(table_name,'_',-1,2)+1,8),'yyyymmdd')   
from user_tables
where table_name like 'WORLD_RI%' 
and table_name not like 'WORLD_RI_ERROR%'
```

Comment: Thanks Randy! there are only 104 tables and I checked each one them and I'm sure there's no odd values which can disobey the datatype conversions.

Comment: @dudisaha, did you check by running the query as suggested by Randy ?

Comment: I've already tried these permutation and combinations. But of no help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it!!

This piece of code works like a charm..Adding one translate on the date string did the trick!
Thanks to all your help.

```
select * from (
select table_name , to_date(substr(table_name,instr(table_name,'_',-1,2)+1,8),'yyyymmdd') as T_DATE , trunc(sysdate) s_date
  from user_tables
 where table_name like 'WORLD_RI%' and table_name not like 'WORLD_RI_ERROR%'
   and translate(substr(table_name,instr(table_name,'_',-1,2)+1,8),'0123456789','$$$$$$$$$$') = '$$$$$$$$'
) where T_DATE < s_date ;
```

Comment: This means that you did have `odd looking values` in your tables names, and with Randy's suggestion you shoud have found them